# Slow Page Loads in all browsers with long idle time to start

Tags: performance, browser, load, google-chrome-devtools

When browsing the internet (all browsers) I experience a significant delay before the page load is initiated.  I've used Chrome's Developer Tools to analyze the issue and in looking at the Performance tab, there is significant Idle time before any activities are started (see image).  In addition, if I look at the network timeline, I see a gap in the waterfall timeline with no activity after the initial page request is made.  Any suggestions as to the root cause or ideas for further troubleshooting?

[Performance Tab in Chrome Developer Tools - page load for Firefox.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtSSW.png)

[Network Tab in Chrome Developer Tools - page load for Google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v5k9.png)

Comment: This isn't the best forum for general computer or networking questions, you might try in Super User instead.

Comment: I've seen this problem reported at least several times and IIRC devtools won't help here. Try looking for the existing solutions, try a new browser profile, a different version of the browser, and other known methods of network issue debugging like chrome://net-internals and whatnot.